# Can I open a mailto link in Gmail and have it sent without clicking "send"?

Tags: jquery, gmail, mailto

I have Gmail configured as my default email app, and I can create open mailto links with it like this:

```
<code>
<textarea id='message' cols='70' rows='5'></textarea><br><button id='news'>Add comment</button>

<script>

$("#news").on("click", function(){
    var text = $("#message").val();
    window.location.href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com?subject=My+great+email+to+you&body=" + text;    
});  

</script>
</code>
```

But I'd like something more. I'd like to send emails without having to click the send button. Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: For your own browser or for people visiting your site?

Comment: This is a private app used by me and other guy, a coworker. We are both Gmail users. I just want an easy way to send email notifications everytime one of us enters new information. So far, I've been using Mandrill (through a rest api) but it's no longer free, and all the alternatives require some server side code.